# How to print values from an input data file from an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a complete beginner programmer so bear with me.

So I have an input text file that I will use as the input into my program in the command window using program.exe < data.txt. The text file has 5 lines, each line has 3 double values, like 30.0 70.0 0.05 etc.

I want to basically use an array of structures to print these input values, like printf("the first value is %f", array[i][0]).

Here is my incorrect code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSOURCES 100

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} coordinates_t;

typedef struct {
    coordinates_t point;
    double w;
} soundsource_t;

coordinates_t a;
soundsource_t b;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    while(scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a.x, &a.y, &b.w) == 3) {
        soundsource_t soundsource[MAXSOURCES][2];
        for (i = 0; i <= MAXSOURCES; i++) {
            printf("%d", soundsource[i][0]);
            printf("%d", soundsource[i][1]);
            printf("%d", soundsource[i][2]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me fix my code? Thanks

Comment: In order to help you, you first have to tell us what is wrong with that code. What output are you expecting, what happens when you run it, etc. Right of the bat I can tell that those `printf`s probably won't return what you are expecting them to (they will print the memory address of your array elements)

Comment: Just to help you with your C coding.  do NOT use typedef statements to define structs.  rather use: struct nameOfStruct { list of fields };  Then create a struct via: struct nameOfStruct myStructName;  reference myStructName via: struct myStrucName.fieldName ...  Then create a pointer to myStructName via: struct nameOfStruct* myStructPtr;    I.E. the use of a typedef struct .... {...} myStructName; is depreciated.

Comment: this line: soundsource_t soundsource[MAXSOURCES][2];  creates an instance of a multidimensional array of soundsource_t struct on the stack.  BUT, no actual values are placed in this multidimensional array.  Your code then tries to print the contents of this array.  Since no contents have been placed in this array, the best that can happen is the garbage/trash from the stack will be printed.

Comment: This line: printf("%d", soundsource[i][2]); is incorrect as there are only 2 entryies available and all C arrays are referenced from 0...(array dimensions-1)

Comment: This line: for (i = 0; i <= MAXSOURCES; i++) { is referencing the stack, one past the end of the soundsource[][] array.  This should be: for (i = 0; i < MAXSOURCES; i++) {  (notice the '<=' changed to just '<')  This is because all C arrays are referenced from 0 to (array dimension-1)

Comment: This line: while(scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a.x, &a.y, &b.w) == 3) { will fail because it does not read the '\n' (newline) at the end of each row in the file.  There are two good ways to get around this problem. 1) read the line via fgets() into a local buffer then use sscanf() to extract each number 2) modify the scanf to something line: while(scanf(" %lf %lf %lf", &a.x, &a.y, &b.w) == 3) {  (notice th additional space in the format string) so it will skip over 'white space', like the newline character(s)\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample to fix

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    soundsource_t soundsource[MAXSOURCES];
    int i, n = 0;

    while(scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a.x, &a.y, &b.w) == 3) {
        soundsource[n].point = a;
        soundsource[n].w = b.w;
        n += 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%f,", soundsource[i].point.x);
        printf("%f ", soundsource[i].point.y);
        printf("%f\n",soundsource[i].w);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read the first comment. However, it seems that you need to study more, so I will you an example of how you could modify your code to achieve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSOURCES 100

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} coordinates_t;

typedef struct {
    coordinates_t point;
    double w;
} soundsource_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, n = 0; // i is a counter and n will be the number of sources we actually read

    // we declare an array of sources, with size MAXSOURCES
    soundsource_t array[MAXSOURCES];

    /*
     * Now every cell of the array is a soundsource_t struct.
     * So, every cell is capable of storing a 'point' and a 'w'.
     */


    // We will read from stdin, three doubles per loop
    // and we will store them in the n-th cell of the array
    while(scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &(array[n].point.x), &(array[n].point.y), &(array[n].w)) == 3) {
        n++; // increment n, so that we keep track of number of sources we read
        if(n == MAXSOURCES) // we reached the limit, so stop reading
          break;
    }

    // print the sources we read. Notice that we go until n and not MAXSOURCES,
    // since we read n sources.
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      // print the i-th cell
      printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", array[i].point.x, array[i].point.y, array[i].w);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.1 0.2 0.3
0.7 0.8 0.9
e <-- here I typed a letter to stop reading from input
0.100000 0.200000 0.300000
0.700000 0.800000 0.900000
```